# "drop partition" functionality in Neo4j, to delete a lot of nodes

Tags: neo4j, database-partitioning

I'm evaluating the use of Neo4j (2.0, but the 1.0 could be used as well) for a project, where a lot of data (millions of nodes) is loaded daily from different sources and is very likely that at some point arbitrary days and sources will have to be entirely deleted, so it must be done quickly.

In Oracle I would use partitioning and create a different partition for each date/source comination, then with a `DROP PARTITION` the removal of them would be fast.
Is there some way to get the same result in Neo4j?

For now, the fastest way I found to label and then possibly delete a lot of nodes is to use a "partition node" linked to them when inserting the data and when necessary traverse the relationships of it and delete all of them, but both in Cypher or using Java APIs the transaction fails because the amount of nodes to remove cannot be stored in memory.

Is there a fastest way to remove all of the nodes with some label previously assigned ?

Comment: Can you add more detail on what you mean by:  "but both in Cypher or using Java APIs the transaction fails because the amount of nodes to remove cannot be stored in memory."

Comment: They do the deletion in a single transaction(at least Cypher, in Java I would iterate over the connected nodes and delete them in a single transaction but could split it in different parts), and to allow the rollback the transaction holds a reference to all the deleted nodes, when there are a lot it consumes all of the memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate approach for partitioning might be to apply a custom label to nodes in that partition.  Nodes can carry as many labels as you like, so:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ create (n:Person:PartitionBLAH {name: "Bob"});
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes created: 1
Properties set: 1
Labels added: 2
850 ms
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n:PartitionBLAH) delete n;
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes deleted: 1
248 ms
```

In this way, we assign "PartitionBLAH" and then delete all nodes with that label (when needed).

Now, as to which is faster - using an index node as you do, or using a custom label - I doubt we can really say.  This is something that will depend on factors like how many nodes you have, how quickly you could find your "partition index" node, and so on.

Comment: I see, but how does Neo4j2.0 handles labels internally? Will it iterate over some label index or is it something like an Oracle partition so it can mark the label as deleted at whole and reuse its segment when needed without iterating on all of the nodes?

Comment: That is a question for the devs.  I just don't know.   Perhaps ask the neo4j google groups?

Comment: OK, so I've been doing some testing, and for warm caches it appears as though using this label approach is much faster.  Creating the data is also a lot faster because normally if you'd be creating via cypher, you'd have to MATCH the index node to create the relationship from it to the new node you just created.  That extra matching slows down data creation as well.